# How to run nosetests without showing of my matplotlib's graph?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, nose

I try to run my test without any messages displaying from my main program. I only want verbose messages from nosetests to display.

For example:

> nosetests -v --nologcapture

All of my printout messages from my main program will be gone.

However, the graph that I call in my main program (`plt.show()` from matplotlib) still shows up.

How do I run the tests without matplotlib's graph showing up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you're calling unittests on your code, so my recommendation would be for you to install the python [Mock](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library. Any tests that will exercise the `plt.show()` function should mock it out to basically do nothing.

Here's an rough example of the idea inside your unittests:

```
from mock import patch


... unittest boiler plate stuff ...

@patch("matplotlib.pyplot.show")
def testMyCode(self, mock_show):
    mock_show.return_value = None  #probably not necessary here in your case
    ... rest of test code ...
```

The `patch` function will override the normal show function with this new `mock_show` which you could name to anything. This should basically make the show now do nothing in your tests and not have the graph show up.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you :)