# Turn off graphs while running unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am testing out my module using the `unittest` library. This includes plotting some graphs using the `matplotlib` library. The issue at the moment is that the testing pauses every time a graph is plotted, and it only resumes after I close the graph. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will model my answer after the simple example code from the matplotlib tutorial: http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Let's assume we have the following module, `plot_graph.py` to be tested:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func_plot():
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func_plot()
```

The calls to `show` can be patched as follows:

```
from plot_graph import func_plot
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("plot_graph.plt.show")
def test_plot(mock_show):
    assert func_plot() == None
```

As you can see, you should patch the calls to `pyplot.show()`. You can find more about patching and mocking in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html.

Usually the section about where to patch is really useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Finally there are similar question already on the site: [How to run nosetests without showing of my matplotlib's graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343640/how-to-run-nosetests-without-showing-of-my-matplotlibs-graph)

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `pyplot.show()` if this is done in the tests. Also the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=show#matplotlib.pyplot.show) suggests using an experimental `block=False` keyword argument to the `show` function.

Comment: `pyplot.show()` is called in one of my modules, not in the tests. `block=False` doesn't work for me. I think its deprecated.

Comment: Maybe calling pyplot.close("all") from your tests could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I ran into a similar issue, but to fix it I had to mock out calls to `matplotlib.pyplot.figure` instead. I realize this isn't exactly what was asked, but this took me a while to figure out after coming across this thread, so I wanted to post it here.

If, for instance, your `plot_graph.py` looked like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func_plot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.show()
```

then, at least in my case (running unit tests on a terminal that has no X11 forwarding and errors out when it tries to open a plot), I needed the following in `test_plot_graph.py` to run my test:

```
from plot_graph import func_plot
from unittest.mock import patch

# unittest boilerplate...

@patch('matplotlib.pyplot.figure')
def test_func_plot(self, mock_fig):
    # whatever tests I want...
    mock_fig.assert_called()  # some assertion on the mock object
```